# System.IO.PathTooLongException and SFTP

Tags: c#, .net, sftp

When you configure SFTP, you aim it at a local folder, right?  It's been a long time since I've done that, and things may have changed since then.

So, if the receiving end's folder path is 248 characters long (the max allowed), but the sftp path (sftp://www.destination.com/folder) isn't, and your application tries to put a file with a 13+ character filename in the SFTP folder (which will bring it over in the 260 character limit for the fully qualified path, but only on the receiving side), will your application still throw a System.IO.PathTooLongException?

My application is throwing that exception, but on my side the path is only 95 characters (69 character path + 26 character filename).  Is it possible I'm actually hitting the character limit on the other end of the SFTP, and that's trickling up into my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the SFTP server can indeed have the same/similar path limit, you would not get `System.IO.PathTooLongException`. That's a local exception. So it's definitely about a too long local path.